# reading .png files into R and create a multiple plot

Tags: r

I am interested in using the following commands to read png files from my computer and making a multiple from them.

```
plot(0:2, 0:2, type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab =      "")
rasterImage(readPNG(source="ArgentinaTotal.png"), 0, 1, 1, 2)
rasterImage(readPNG(source="BrazilTotal.png"), 1, 1, 2, 2)
rasterImage(readPNG(source="ChileTotal.png"), 0, 0, 1, 1)
rasterImage(readPNG(source="ColombiaTotal.png"), 1, 0, 2, 1)
```

The commands work fine for a 2X2 setup but what should I do if I want to have multiple of 2 columns and 4 rows?
I used the following code:

```
plot(0:2, 0:4, type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

But I get an error message:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
   'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Answer (score 5):

All you need is to properly specify `xlim` and `ylim` in your `plot` call.
For example:

```
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))

plot(NA, xlim = c(0, 2), ylim = c(0, 4), type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
rasterImage(img, 1, 3, 2, 4)
rasterImage(img, 1, 2, 2, 3)
rasterImage(img, 1, 1, 2, 2)
rasterImage(img, 1, 0, 2, 1)
```

And here is an example output:
[image: example output]